# upper bound on $L_2$-norm of a power series, in terms of coefficients?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, entire-functions

Is there any upper bound on $L_2$-norm of a convergent power series (in R), in terms of coefficients?
I have $f(x) = a_0+a_1\frac{x}{1!}+a_2\frac{x^2}{2!}+a_3\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$.

I need something like:
$$
\|f\|^2_{L_2({\mathbb R})}\leq r(a_0, a_1, a_2,\cdots)
$$
where $r(a_0, a_1, a_2,\cdots) = \sum_{ij}c_{ij}a^\ast_i a_j$ is some infinite positive definite quadratic form.

Comment: In fact, I have $a_0^2+a_1^2+...=1$

Comment: power function has $\infty$ as integral

Comment: Still power gives $\infty$

Comment: In general, $||f||_{L_2}$ is not bounded (because polynomials have unbounded norm). My question is there any bound, in terms of maybe some entropic properties of $\{a_i\}$

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2088795/42969.

Comment: Check this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258777/when-is-an-analytic-function-in-l2-bbb-r  It looks like the question is not so easy to answer